# Improve Loading time for query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I've got this script, but the it's taking a long time to load, and sometimes exceeds the loading time, is there a way i can improve the loading time?

```
public static function getSubAreas() {

    // Get database object from global scope
    global $database;

    if(isset($_GET['PostAreaRef'])){ $PostAreaRef = trim($_GET['PostAreaRef']); } else { $PostAreaRef = "0"; }


    $resultA = $database->execute("SELECT AgentRef FROM SearchGroupsAgent WHERE SearchGroupRef = '21'");
    $AgentRefs = array();
    while($rowA = $database->fetch($resultA)) {
        $AgentRefs[] = '\''.$rowA['AgentRef'].'\''; 
    }
    $AgentRefs = implode(',',$AgentRefs);


    // Build database query
    $sql = "SELECT SubAreaRef, count(*) AS Count FROM PropertySale WHERE StatusRef = 1  AND Archived = 0 AND AgentRef IN ($AgentRefs) GROUP BY SubAreaRef ORDER BY Count DESC";

    // Get data from database
    $result = $database->execute($sql);

    // Initialize array to hold objects
    $objects = array();

    // Fetch rows from database cursor
    while($row = $database->fetch($result)) {

        $object = new self;

        $GroupAreaSQL = $database->execute("SELECT ID,SubArea FROM SubArea WHERE ID =  '".$row['SubAreaRef']."'");
        $GroupArea = $database->fetch($GroupAreaSQL);

        if ($GroupArea['SubArea'] == "-- Not Specified --")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if ($GroupArea['AreaRef'] == $PostAreaRef)
                {
                    // Initialize object's attributes
                    $object->ID = $GroupArea['ID'];
                    $object->SubArea = $GroupArea['SubArea'];
                    $object->Count = $row['Count'];
                    $objects[] = $object;
                }
            }


    }

    // Return array of objects
    return $objects;
}
```

And this code:

```
   public static function getAreas2() {



    $db = odbc_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD);  

    $resultA = odbc_exec($db, "SELECT AgentRef FROM SearchGroupsAgent WHERE SearchGroupRef = '21'");
    $AgentRefs = array();
    while($rowA = odbc_fetch_array($resultA)) {
        $AgentRefs[] = '\''.$rowA['AgentRef'].'\''; 
    }
    $AgentRefs = implode(',',$AgentRefs);


    $query = odbc_exec($db, "SELECT  ID,Area FROM Area ORDER BY Area"); 
    while($Area = odbc_fetch_array($query))
      {                    
         $Counter = 0;
         $query2 = odbc_exec($db, "SELECT  ID,SubArea FROM SubArea WHERE AreaRef = '".$Area['ID']."' ");  
         while($SubArea = odbc_fetch_array($query2))
         {
            if ($SubArea['SubArea'] != "-- Not Specified --")
            {
              $result3 = odbc_exec($db, "SELECT count(*) AS Count FROM PropertySale WHERE StatusRef = 1  AND Archived = 0 AND SubAreaRef = '".$SubArea['ID']."' AND AgentRef IN ($AgentRefs)");
              $PropertySale = odbc_fetch_array($result3);
              if ($PropertySale['Count'] > 0)
              {
                $AreaID = $Area['ID'];
                $AreaName = $Area['Area'];
                $Counter = $Counter + $PropertySale['Count'];
              }

            }
            else
            {
              $AreaID = $Area['ID'];
              $AreaName = "";
              $Counter = $Counter;
            }

         }

        if ($Counter != 0)
        {
            $object = new self;
             // Initialize object's attributes
            $object->ID = $AreaID;
            $object->Area = $AreaName;
            $object->Count = $Counter;
            $objects[] = $object;
        }

      } 

    // Return array of objects
    return $objects;
}
```

These are my tables:

Area:
ID, Area

SubArea:
ID, SubArea, AreaRef

PropertySale:
ID, Address, SubAreaRef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think potentially your code could result in the execution of many SQL statements.  That can be costly, especially if your are access your database via TCP which is likely the case with ODBC.

You must look for a way to reduce the number of SQL statements you have to execute and therefore the number of network round trips which are a costly operation.  I can't pull the syntax off the top of my head but I think you could reduce this to a single SQL statement by executing a statement that joins the three tables that hold your data.

Then you would only need to execute a single statement and the info you want would come back in a single result set.  That should greatly reduce the number of network round trips so you should see a performance increase.  Reducing network round trips is always something to consider when coding an app for data access.

[Here](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=support&utm_term=ber&utm_content=odbc) is a link to a tutorial on SQL JOIN syntax that might help you get started.